# Find the index of the first digit in a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string like

```
"xdtwkeltjwlkejt7wthwk89lk"
```

how can I get the index of the first digit in the string?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search):

```
>>> import re
>>> s1 = "thishasadigit4here"
>>> m = re.search(r"\d", s1)
>>> if m:
...     print("Digit found at position", m.start())
... else:
...     print("No digit in that string")
... 
Digit found at position 13
```

Comment: In case anyone is interested in performance, I did some quit timeit work on a few different approaches - regular expressions are the fastest: https://gist.github.com/1683249

Comment: What would you use instead of `m.start()` in order to get what digit is found (in this case 4)?

Comment: @zanahorias you can use `m.group(0)`

Comment: It has been a long time since @umbrae's benchmark and currently on Python 3.7.8 the `isdigit()` method is consistently faster for me by about 5-6%.

Answer (score 39):

Here is a better and more flexible way, regex is overkill here.

```
s = 'xdtwkeltjwlkejt7wthwk89lk'

for i, c in enumerate(s):
    if c.isdigit():
        print(i)
        break
```

output:

```
15
```

To get all digits and their positions, a simple expression will do

```
>>> [(i, c) for i, c in enumerate('xdtwkeltjwlkejt7wthwk89lk') if c.isdigit()]
[(15, '7'), (21, '8'), (22, '9')]
```

Or you can create a dict of digit and its last position

```
>>> {c: i for i, c in enumerate('xdtwkeltjwlkejt7wthwk89lk') if c.isdigit()}
{'9': 22, '8': 21, '7': 15}
```

Answer (score 21):

Thought I'd toss my method on the pile.  I'll do just about anything to avoid regex.

```
sequence = 'xdtwkeltjwlkejt7wthwk89lk'
i = [x.isdigit() for x in sequence].index(True)
```

To explain what's going on here:

- `[x.isdigit() for x in sequence]` is going to translate the string into an array of booleans representing whether each character is a digit or not
- `[...].index(True)` returns the first index value that `True` is found in.

Comment: This will raise a `ValueError` if your string has no digits.

Answer (score 10):

```
import re
first_digit = re.search('\d', 'xdtwkeltjwlkejt7wthwk89lk')
if first_digit:
    print(first_digit.start())
```

Answer (score 10):

Seems like a good job for a parser:

```
>>> from simpleparse.parser import Parser
>>> s = 'xdtwkeltjwlkejt7wthwk89lk'
>>> grammar = """
... integer := [0-9]+
... <alpha> := -integer+
... all     := (integer/alpha)+
... """
>>> parser = Parser(grammar, 'all')
>>> parser.parse(s)
(1, [('integer', 15, 16, None), ('integer', 21, 23, None)], 25)
>>> [ int(s[x[1]:x[2]]) for x in parser.parse(s)[1] ]
[7, 89]
```

Comment: Surely overkill for this, but a nice recipe to be featured here!

Comment: @jsbueno: thanks, indeed an overkill (at least until you have to extend the pattern matching, sometimes I have a hard time understanding a regex I wrote two months before) :-)

Comment: This answer taught me more about how to use simpleparse than any tutorial.

Answer (score 7):

To get all indexes do:

```
idxs = [i for i in range(0, len(string)) if string[i].isdigit()]
```

Then to get the first index do:

```
if len(idxs):
    print(idxs[0])
else:
    print('No digits exist')
```

Comment: `IndexError` will be raised if your string has no digits.

Comment: one-liner is better !

Answer (score 3):

As the other solutions say, to find the index of the first digit in the string we can use regular expressions:

```
>>> s = 'xdtwkeltjwlkejt7wthwk89lk'
>>> match = re.search(r'\d', s)
>>> print match.start() if match else 'No digits found'
15
>>> s[15] # To show correctness
'7'
```

While simple, a regular expression match is going to be overkill for super-long strings. A more efficient way is to iterate through the string like this:

```
>>> for i, c in enumerate(s):
...     if c.isdigit():
...         print i
...         break
... 
15
```

In case we wanted to extend the question to finding the first *integer* (not digit) and what it was:

```
>>> s = 'xdtwkeltjwlkejt711wthwk89lk'
>>> for i, c in enumerate(s):
...     if c.isdigit():
...         start = i
...         while i < len(s) and s[i].isdigit():
...             i += 1
...         print 'Integer %d found at position %d' % (int(s[start:i]), start)
...         break
... 
Integer 711 found at position 15
```

Comment: you can find the position in the match object. See my solution.

Answer (score 3):

In **Python 3.8+** you can use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) to look for the first `\d` (for **d**igit) character class like this:

```
import re

my_string = "xdtwkeltjwlkejt7wthwk89lk"

if first_digit := re.search(r"\d", my_string):
    print(first_digit.start())
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are multiple solutions, but using regular expressions you can do this:

```
>>> import re
>>> match = re.search("\d", "xdtwkeltjwlkejt7wthwk89lk")
>>> match.start(0)
15
```

Comment: `AttributeError` will be raised if your string doesn't have any digits.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another regex-less way, more in a functional style. This one finds the position of the first occurrence of each digit that exists in the string, then chooses the lowest. A regex is probably going to be more efficient, especially for longer strings (this makes at least 10 full passes through the string and up to 20).

```
haystack = "xdtwkeltjwlkejt7wthwk89lk"
digits   = "012345689"
found    = [haystack.index(dig) for dig in digits if dig in haystack]
firstdig = min(found) if found else None
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expression

```
import re
y = "xdtwkeltjwlkejt7wthwk89lk"

s = re.search("\d",y).start()
```

Comment: `AttributeError` will be raised if your string doesn't have any digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
def first_digit_index(iterable):
    try:
        return next(i for i, d in enumerate(iterable) if d.isdigit())
    except StopIteration:
        return -1
```

This does not use regex and will stop iterating as soon as the first digit is found.

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
result = "  Total files:...................     90"
match = re.match(r".*[^\d](\d+)$", result)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

will output

```
90
```

Comment: Please, consider adding a short explanation of the code in your answer.

Comment: This returns the first set of digits, not just the first digit.

Comment: this only works if the last char is a digit

Answer (score -1):

```
instr = 'nkfnkjbvhbef0njhb h2konoon8ll'
numidx = next((i for i, s in enumerate(instr) if s.isdigit()), None)
print(numidx)
```

Output:

```
12
```

`numidx` will be the index of the first occurrence of a digit in `instr`. If there are no digits in `instr`, `numidx` will be `None`.

I didn't see this solution here, and thought it should be.

Comment: I'm not sure how you missed it, but this isn't any different from the [second most upvoted answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4510805).