# Parsing integers from an alphanumeric string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have an alphanumeric code that looks like:

```
"PRODUCTNAME600COUPON50"
```

where `PRODUCTNAME` is a variable of inconsistent length

I want to be able to extract the integer values of the string into a list- in this case `[600, 50]`.

I'm looking for a slick Pythonic way to do it- I started with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4510709/165673) for finding the index of the first number within a string, but that falls short in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use the following regex:

```
In [67]: strs="PRODUCTNAME600COUPON50"

In [68]: re.findall(r'\d+',strs)
Out[68]: ['600', '50']
```

to get integers:

```
In [69]: map(int,re.findall(r'\d+',strs))
Out[69]: [600, 50]
```